# Is it normal to have regular model for GET and "flat" model for POST from Design REST point of view?

Tags: rest

The questions about possibility to have different models for POST and GET methods in REST api have been asked several times but I would like to clarify one specific moment.
Suppose we are designing api about sport competition.

Models and corresponding resources:

```
1) Player
{  "id" : 2,
   "firstName" : "Nikolay",
   "lastName": "Grigoryan",
   ..... 
}
```

/players/2

2) Tournament

```
{ "id" 1,
  "name": "Some tournament",
  "date" "01.02.2019",
  .......
}
```

/tournaments/1

3) Participant

```
{
  "id": 2,
   "tournament": { "id" 1,
      "name": "Some tournament",
      "date" "01.02.2019",
      .......
    },
   "player": {  "id" : 2,
     "firstName" : "Nikolay",
     "lastName": "Grigoryan",
     ..... 
   }
}
```

/tournament/1/participants/2

When I'm requesting the participants of the certain tournament it's convinient enough to have a separate field by name player containg full nested Player model whith all available fields. But when I'm creating a new participant the situation looks different for me. I would prefer to have just playerId to provide as POST body:

/tournament/1/participants

POST

```
{
  ....,
  playerId: 2,
  .....
}
```

but not

```
{
  ....,
  "player": {
    "id": 2,
   ....
  }
}
```

It seems no need to have nested model here but instead only playerId is enough and by this reason no need to have nested object only for holding id at all.

Is it ok to have such simplification of model for POST request or they should be of the same structure? Probably I miss something important by doing such conclusion. If so I would be grateful for explanation what exactly it is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it ok to have such simplification of model for POST request or they should be of the same structure? Probably I miss something important by doing such conclusion. If so I would be grateful for explanation what exactly it is.

How would you do this as a web site?

You'd probably have some sort of form, with a drop down control that lists the identifiers that you might use.  The client would choose the identifier from the list, and submit the form.  The result would be an HTTP request message with the identifier in the request body.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

Unfortunately I didn't catch your point.
More exactly I didn't understand what is your advice in my case- to use the same model in both cases (POST and GET) or not?

Comment: About possible client use case- yes of couse, probably user should choose needed Player from drop-down list and  Http request will be sent to the server with information about tournament and player to add. For Post request I can only send ID for this player. But for GET request I would like to get all information about player, associated with given tournament in one request, without need to send additional requests by player id.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to at least take inspiration of is to look at [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html).

If a tournament has players, and this is a many-to-many relation it might make sense for players to be associated to a tournament via a link.

- To get a list of players, you would simply embed the player resources.
- To identify players, you don't use their id, you use their url.
- To associate players to a tournament, you could update the links.

As an aside I think that having models that are identical for both receiving (GET) and sending (POST) is a very nice property and makes things easier to understand, but it's also completely fine to abandon this rule where appropriate. I find that especially the situation where people often need a different approach is the case where multiple resources / models are associated with each other. There's not one elegant way to solve this, but using links instead of id's might give you some tools to solve this in a general manner that is applicable everywhere.